# Can you un-shorthand this statement?

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I am trying to understand this part of a module:

```
(isOwner
    ? canSort || (revert = !rootEl.contains(dragEl)) 
    : (
        putSortable === this ||
        activeGroup.checkPull(this, activeSortable, dragEl, evt) && group.checkPut(this, activeSortable, dragEl, evt)
      )
)
```

Could someone "un-shorthand" this for me? 
This is part of an IF statement and returns true/false.

Comment: Which bit don't you understand?

Comment: Writing in this style make him unsure/cannot understand the logic => hard to maintain.

Comment: Well yeah. That's why Delcon is asking this question.

Comment: Yes! I never made friends with all those shorthand's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look likes this:

```
if (isOwner) {
    if (canSort) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return (revert = !rootEl.contains(dragEl));
    }
} else {
  if (putSortable === this) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return activeGroup.checkPull(this, activeSortable, dragEl, evt) && group.checkPut(this, activeSortable, dragEl, evt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you understand how the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) works in JavaScript.

If "isOwner" is true, it will return this:

```
canSort || (revert = !rootEl.contains(dragEl))
```

otherwise, it will return this:

```
putSortable === this ||
activeGroup.checkPull(this, activeSortable, dragEl, evt) && group.checkPut(this, activeSortable, dragEl, evt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, it looks like it is setting a boolean value. If you were to expand it out, it would look something like this:

```
var something;
if (isOwner) {
  if (canSort != undefined && canSort !== 0) {
    something = true;
  }
  else {
    something = (revert = !rootEl.contains(dragEl));
  }
}
else {
  if (putSortable === this) {
    something = true;
  }
  else {
    something = (activeGroup.checkpull(this, activeSortable, dragEl, evt) && group.checkPut(this, activeSortable, dragEl, evt));
  }
}
```